# Swagger-hapi: path /models generate errors

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

The following NodeJS Hapi code generate an error when querying at http://localhost:3000/documentation

If I change the path of the endpoint to something else than **/models**, like **/users** for instance, everything works well. It looks like the endpoint **/models** is reserved.

Any idea why any other endpoint work except **/models**? How can I fix it? I can't change the URL as too many people use it.

```
var Hapi            = require('hapi'),
    Inert           = require('inert'),
    Vision          = require('vision'),
    Joi             = require('joi'),
    HapiSwagger     = require('hapi-swagger')


var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000
});

var swaggerOptions = {
    apiVersion: "1.0"
};

server.register([
    Inert,
    Vision,
    {
        register: HapiSwagger,
        options: swaggerOptions
    }], function (err) {
    server.start(function(){
        // Add any server.route() config here
        console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
    });
});

server.route(
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/models',
        config: {
            handler: function (request, reply) {
                reply("list of models")
            },
            description: 'Get todo',
            notes: 'Returns a todo item by the id passed in the path',
            tags: ['api'],
            validate: {
                params: {
                    username: Joi.number()
                        .required()
                        .description('the id for the todo item')
                }
            }
        }
    }
)



server.start(function(){
    // Add any server.route() config here
    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `models` is part of swagger's internal structure and it looks like there is an issue in the `swagger.js` file when dealing with endpoints that use models as part of the URL for an endpoint.

The easy fix for this is to use a `nickname`. This changes the internal ref in swagger, but the UI should still say `models` and it will fire against your endpoint correctly.

```
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/models/{username}',
    config: {
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            reply("list of models")
        },
        description: 'Get todo',
        notes: 'Returns a todo item by the id passed in the path',
        tags: ['api'],
        plugins: {
            'hapi-swagger': {
              nickname: 'modelsapi'
            }
          },
        validate: {
            params: {
                username: Joi.number()
                    .required()
                    .description('the id for the todo item')
            }
        }
    }
}
```